# angular slickgrid not loading after page routing in Angular 7

Tags: angular, slickgrid

I have a common slickgrid component in my app. This slickgrid component is added inside others component. So when my app is loading for the First time,Slickgrid working properly, but when I route to another component or came back to the first component, it's displaying blank. If I reload the page, it's working properly.Below is my code snippet:

grid.component.ts:

```
columnDefinitions: Column[];
gridOptions1: GridOption;
dataset1: any[];

ngOnInit(): void {
this.columnDefinitions = [
  {id: 'title', name: 'Title', field: 'title', sortable: true},
  {id: 'duration', name: 'Duration (days)', field: 'duration', sortable: true},
  {id: '%', name: '% Complete', field: 'percentComplete', sortable: true},
  {id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start'},
  {id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish'},
  {id: 'effort-driven', name: 'Effort Driven', field: 'effortDriven', sortable: true}
];
this.gridOptions1 = {
  enableAutoResize: true,
  enableSorting: true
};

this.mockData();
}

mockData() {
  // mock a dataset
  const mockDataset = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   const randomYear = 2000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   const randomMonth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
   const randomDay = Math.floor((Math.random() * 29));
   const randomPercent = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

  mockDataset[i] = {
    id: i,
    title: 'Task ' + i,
    duration: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '',
    percentComplete: randomPercent,
    start: `${randomMonth}/${randomDay}/${randomYear}`,
    finish: `${randomMonth}/${randomDay}/${randomYear}`,
    effortDriven: (i % 5 === 0)
  };
}

this.dataset1 = mockDataset;
}
```

grid.component.html:

```
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
               [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
               [gridOptions]="gridOptions1"
               [dataset]="dataset1"
               gridHeight="300"
               gridWidth="800">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

test1.component.html:

```
<app-grid #commonGrid >

</app-grid>
```

test2.component.html:

```
 <app-grid #commonGrid >

</app-grid>
```

app.component.html:

```
   <a routerLink="test">Test</a>
   <a routerLink="test1">Test1</a>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

After every page routing,the grid goes blank.How to solve this problem

Comment: Please add a minimal working example at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Getting some error while creating a project in stackblitz using github repo.You can find the codebase from here https://github.com/Subham10/angular-fkyuqp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **different ids** as `gridId` property for each component.

As one solution you can pass these ids from the test.components to your home component as input.

E.g.

home.component.html: adpat gridId `<angular-slickgrid gridId="{{gridId}}" ...`

home.component.ts: add input `@Input() gridId: string;`

test.component.ts: add gridId property `gridId = "gridId1"`

test1.component.ts: add gridId property `gridId = "gridId2"`

testX.component.html: adapt html bindings `<app-home [gridId]="gridId"></app-home>`

Edit:
I uploaded the changes to a [git repo](https://github.com/zerocewl/angular-fkyuqp/commit/62c1aebc6dfb098b7b1d2b518aeab039ccc422ee)

Comment: It's working.Is there any change in angular-slickgrid version 1.x and 2.x, cause the previous code was running fine in angular-cli 6.x.x and slickgrid version 1.x.x . After upgrading, this issue is coming.

Comment: Have a look at the [slickgrid page](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Migration-from-1.x-to-2.x), there should be some infos about the breaking changes. Please vote up the answere, if it solves your prob https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote