# Angular SlickGrid Dynamic grid inside md-tab not loading the definitions

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

Angular slick grid is not loading using the md-tab

In the child component will be created once the md tab is created. Am setting the tab configurations on ngOnInit method of the child component ts.

Am not sure what am missing here.

If the tab is already loaded then am getting the dom doesnot exists error.

**Parent.html**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value"  (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            ...
        </ng-template>
        Content 1
        <div class="container col-12" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
                      [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                      [dataset]="dataset"
                      (sgOnSelectedRowsChanged)="onSelectedRowsChanged($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)"
                      (sgOnClick)="onCellClicked($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)"
                      >
            </angular-slickgrid>
          </div>
    </mat-tab>
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="d-flex">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex ml-4">
                <a class="" (click)="removeTab(tab)"> 
                    <span class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    Content of {{tab}}
    <div class="container col-12" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [id]="tab" >
        Table : {{tab}}
        <child-details [id]="tab" [query]="tab"></child-details> 
      </div>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**ParentComponent**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  columnDefinitions: Column[] = [];
  gridOptions: GridOption = {};
  dataset: any[] = [];
  angularGrid: AngularGridInstance;

  constructor( private angularUtilService: AngularUtilService,private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.prepareGrid()

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    sessionStorage.setItem("pinnedTabs", this.tabs.join('|'));
  }

  inputValue: string = "";

  tabs = [];
  selected = new FormControl(0);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('pinnedTabs') !== null && sessionStorage.getItem('pinnedTabs') !== undefined && sessionStorage.getItem('pinnedTabs').trim() !== "") {
      this.tabs = sessionStorage.getItem('pinnedTabs').split('|');
    }

  }

  removeTab(tabName: string) {
    this.tabs.splice(this.tabs.indexOf(tabName), 1);
    sessionStorage.setItem("pinnedTabs", this.tabs.join('|'));
  }

  addNewTab(tabName: string) {
    console.log("Added new tab")
    if (this.tabs.indexOf(tabName) === -1) {
      this.tabs.push(tabName);
    }
    this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.indexOf(tabName) + 1);
    sessionStorage.setItem("pinnedTabs", this.tabs.join('|'));
  }

  getConfigurations() : Observable<JobListConfig[]>{
    return this.http.get<...[]>('...');
  }


  prepareGrid() {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        "id": "id", "name": "id", "field": "id", "sortable": true, type: FieldType.number, "filterable": true, "filter": { model: Filters.compoundInputNumber }, formatter(rowIndex, cellIndex, value, columnObject, rowObject, grid) {
          return "<label class='pointer' (click)=addNewTab(" + rowObject.id + ")>" + rowObject.jobId + "</label>";
        }
      }
      .....
    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      enableAutoResize: true,
      enableSorting: true,
      enablePagination: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCellNavigation: true,
      datasetIdPropertyName: "id",
      createPreHeaderPanel: true,
      showPreHeaderPanel: true,
      alwaysShowVerticalScroll: false,
      //autoHeight: true,
      autoResize: {
        containerId: 'demo-container',
        sidePadding: 15
      },
      
      pagination: {
        pageSize:10,
        pageSizes:[10,15,20]
      },
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      rowSelectionOptions: {
        // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
        selectActiveRow: false
      },

      //headerRowHeight: 40,
      //rowHeight: 60
   //   preHeaderPanelHeight: 28,
     // colspanCallback: this.renderDifferentColspan,
    };

    // fill the dataset with your data
    this.dataset = this.mockData();
  }

  onSelectedRowsChanged(e, args) {
    // user clicked on the 1st column, multiple checkbox selection
    console.log('multiple row checkbox selected', event, args);
  }

  onCellClicked(e, args) {
    // when clicking on any cell, we will make it the new selected row
    // however, we don't want to interfere with multiple row selection checkbox which is on 1st column cell

    if(args.cell !== 0 && args.grid.getColumns()[args.cell].id==="id"){
      this.addNewTab(args.grid.getData().getItems()[args.row]["id"])
    }
  }

  mockData() {
    // mock a dataset
    const mockDataset = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      mockDataset[i] = {
        "id": i,
        ....
      };
    }

    return mockDataset;
  }

  tabChanged(event) {
    console.log("Tab changed");
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

**ChildTemplate html**

```
<angular-slickgrid [gridId]="query" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
   [dataset]="dataset" (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)">
   </angular-slickgrid>
```

```
export class ChildCompoent implements OnInit {

  @Input() query: Array<any>;

  private angularGrid: AngularGridInstance;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Ng On init")
    console.log(this.query);
    this.prepareGrid();
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   

  }

  columnDefinitions: Column[] = [];
  gridOptions: GridOption = {};
  dataset: any[] = [];

  prepareGrid() {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
      {
        "id": "id", "name": "id", "field": "id", "sortable": true, type: FieldType.number, "filterable": true, "filter": { model: Filters.compoundInputNumber }, formatter(rowIndex, cellIndex, value, columnObject, rowObject, grid) {
          return "<label class='pointer' (click)=addNewTab(" + rowObject.id + ")>" + rowObject.jobId + "</label>";
        }
      }
      ....
      },

    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
      enableAutoResize: true,
      enableSorting: true,
      enablePagination: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCellNavigation: true,
      datasetIdPropertyName: "id",
      createPreHeaderPanel: true,
      showPreHeaderPanel: true,
      alwaysShowVerticalScroll: false,
      //autoHeight: true,
      autoResize: {
        containerId: 'demo-container',
        sidePadding: 15
      },

      pagination: {
        pageSize: 10,
        pageSizes: [10, 15, 20]
      },
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      rowSelectionOptions: {
        // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
        selectActiveRow: false
      },

      //headerRowHeight: 40,
      //rowHeight: 60
      //   preHeaderPanelHeight: 28,
      // colspanCallback: this.renderDifferentColspan,
    };

    // fill the dataset with your data
    this.dataset = this.mockData();
  }

  mockData() {
    // mock a dataset
    const mockDataset = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

      mockDataset[i] = {
        "id": i,
        ....
      };
    }

    return mockDataset;
  }


  angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
    console.log('slickgrid created');
    this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
  }

  onTabSelected(tab){
    console.log("Tab selected")
    this.angularGrid.resizerService.resizeGrid();
  }
}
```

Sample screen shot

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's very obvious, the console error tells you everything you need to know... SlickGrid requires a DOM element as container and you're not passing a valid one, in fact you're passing an array which is not a string. Also possible duplicate of this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60447604/angular-slickgrid-not-loading-after-page-routing-in-angular-7/60454800#60454800)

Comment: @ghiscoding Thanks.
I have tried modifying the assigned to a variable. Still getting the same issue.
child component
`
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Ng On init")
    console.log(this.query);
    this.gridId = "slickGrid-"+this.query.indexOf(0);
    this.prepareGrid();
  }
`
child html
`
<div *ngIf="gridId" [id]="gridId" class="container col-12">
<angular-slickgrid [gridId]="gridId" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
   [dataset]="dataset" (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)">
   </angular-slickgrid>
   </div>
`

Comment: onAngularGridCreated event is not getting triggered for the child component even once. The example repo given out the the above link you shared seems to have the same issue, Grid is loading once and further its not loading @ghiscoding

Comment: The `(onAngularGridCreated)` will only get fired if it creates the grid, which never happens in your case because again you don't have the correct gridId, so that it normal behavior. You have to remember that you need to initialize/prepare the grid with its column definitions and for that you need to have a DOM element container for the grid that is found by the `gridId` and it can't find it in your case because it doesn't exist, it doesn't find the container and so the process is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved by adding the style to the container as below and wrapped that with `<ng-template matTabContent>`

```
    <ng-template matTabContent>
    <child-details class="container col-12" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [id]="tab" [query]="tab" ></child-details> 
</ng-template>
```